# javascript - javascript between <script> tag is not executed in sequential order

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code for making a 2048 game with a onkeydown function to detect when user presses arrow keys. I thought the code is executed in sequential order but the onkeydown doesn't work if i put it at the end but only works if i put it first, even before canvas and tiles array declaration. How can i fix this so the order of execution makes more sense to me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var Tile = function(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.value = "";
    }

    Tile.prototype.draw = function() {
        ctx.fillStyle = "green";
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 100, 100);
    }

    Tile.prototype.setX = function(x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    Tile.prototype.setY = function(y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    Tile.prototype.getY = function() {
        return this.y;
    }

    Tile.prototype.getX = function() {
        return this.x;
    }

    var tiles = [];

    for(let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        for(let j = 1; j <= 4; j++) {
            tiles.push(new Tile(j * 110, i * 110));
        }
    }

    for(let i = 0; i <= tiles.length; i++) {
        tiles[i].draw();
    }

    document.onkeydown = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        if (e.keyCode == '38') {
            for(let i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++) {
                tiles[i].setY(tiles[i].getY() - 50);
                tiles[i].draw();
            }
        }
        else if (e.keyCode == '40') {
            for(let i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++) {
                tiles[i].setY(tiles[i].getY() + 50);
                tiles[i].draw();
            }
        }
        else if (e.keyCode == '37') {
            for(let i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++) {
                tiles[i].setX(tiles[i].getX() - 50);
                tiles[i].draw();
            }
        }
        else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
           for(let i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++) {
                tiles[i].setX(tiles[i].getX() + 50);
                tiles[i].draw();
            }
        }

    };
</script>
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Don't omit semicolons from `var` statements and prototype assignments.

Comment: That code will definitely be executed sequentially, except of course that the contents of the function you assign to `onclick` won't be executed until a click occurs. What problem, specifically, are you having with it?

Comment: Side note: This is incorrect: `for(let i = 0; i <= tiles.length; i++`. It should be `<`, not `<=`. Which may be the problem: Since that throws an error (you try to call `undefined` as a functino), your click handler is never assigned.

Comment: The onkeydown function works fine if i put it at the beginning but it does not work if i put it at the end.

Comment: @ThuanNguyen - See my comment above. Also, be sure to open your web console so you can see the errors you get from your code.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes it works now, my code editor doesn't have syntax checking. Thank you!!!

Comment: There was no syntax problem. (But I recommend getting an editor that will help with syntax, such as VS Code.)

Comment: Next time try pressing F12 in the browser, it'll open the developer tools and show the error in the console tab.